# Wordpress Remove Slug from Custom Post

Tags: php, wordpress

My Permalink structure is set to be: `%category%/%postname%/`

I want to remove the slug from my custom post and I found the following solution:

```
 function gp_add_cpt_post_names_to_main_query( $query ) {
    // Bail if this is not the main query.
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }
    // Bail if this query doesn't match our very specific rewrite rule.
    if ( ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) || 2 !== count( $query->query ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // Bail if we're not querying based on the post name.
    if ( empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // Add CPT to the list of post types WP will include when it queries based on the post name.
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'credit-cards' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'gp_add_cpt_post_names_to_main_query' );
```

However, it works only when my permalink is set to `/%postname%/`

Any ideas how to make it works with: `%category%/%postname%/` structure?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your function.php and update your-post-type

```
function vipx_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'event' ) ) || 'publish' != $post->post_status )
        return $post_link;

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
     }
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'vipx_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );

function vipx_parse_request_tricksy( $query ) {

// Only noop the main query
if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
    return;

// Only noop our very specific rewrite rule match
if ( 2 != count( $query->query )
    || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) )
    return;

// 'name' will be set if post permalinks are just post_name, otherwise the page rule will match
if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'your_post_type', 'page' ) );
}
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'vipx_parse_request_tricksy' );
```

Comment: get 404 because my permalinks is set to be `%category%/%postname%/`